# C# TCP connection lost

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

for the following code, my client makes a request to the server, but immediately as it does (after it connects successfully), I get this error "Network Error". I have been looking for extra info on it with the debugger but no luck. All of this is with the firewall down.

The connection lost event gives me the "Network error" generic message.

```
public class Server
{
    private ServerConnectionContainer serverConnectionContainer;

    public void StartServer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the server port and press return:");
        string port = Console.ReadLine();

        //1. Start listen on a port
        serverConnectionContainer = ConnectionFactory.CreateServerConnectionContainer(int.Parse(port), false);
        serverConnectionContainer.ConnectionLost += (a, b, c) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{serverConnectionContainer.Count} {b.ToString()} Connection lost {a.IPRemoteEndPoint.Port}. Reason {c.ToString()}");
            };

        serverConnectionContainer.ConnectionEstablished += connectionEstablished;
        serverConnectionContainer.AllowUDPConnections = true;

        serverConnectionContainer.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Server started");

        while (true) {

        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// We got a connection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connection">The connection we got. (TCP or UDP)</param>
    private void connectionEstablished(Connection connection, ConnectionType type)
    {
        connection.EnableLogging = true;
        connection.LogIntoStream(Console.OpenStandardOutput());

        Console.WriteLine($"{serverConnectionContainer.Count} {connection.GetType()} connected on port {connection.IPRemoteEndPoint.Port}");

        //3. Register packet listeners.
        connection.RegisterPacketHandler<TrainerRequest>(TrainerRequestReceived, this);
    }

    private void TrainerRequestReceived(TrainerRequest req, Connection connection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"RawDataPacket received. Data: {string.Join(", ", req.Data["pos_ally"])}");

        var test = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();
        test.Add("pos_ally", new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });

        connection.Send(new TrainerResponse(test, req));
    }
}

public class Client
{
    public static async Task StartClient()
    {
        //Request server IP and port number
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the server IP in the format 192.168.0.1 and press return:");
        string ip = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the server port and press return:");
        string port = Console.ReadLine();

        //Parse the necessary information out of the provided string
        ConnectionResult connectionResult = ConnectionResult.TCPConnectionNotAlive;
        //1. Establish a connection to the server.
        TcpConnection tcpConnection = ConnectionFactory.CreateTcpConnection(ip, int.Parse(port), out connectionResult);

        //2. Register what happens if we get a connection
        if (connectionResult == ConnectionResult.Connected)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{tcpConnection.ToString()} Connection established");
            //3. Send a raw data packet request.
            tcpConnection.KeepAlive = true;

            while (true)
            {
                var test = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();
                test.Add("pos_ally", new byte[] { 5, 6, 7, 8 });

                var res = await tcpConnection.SendAsync<TrainerResponse>(new TrainerRequest { Data = test });

                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ServerConnectionContainer` is not a part of .Net Framework, what is it? In string interpolation there is no need to call `.ToString()`, string interpolation will do that. I suspect that your `while(true)` blocks the thread - this could be a problem depending on how this server component is implemented. Replace it with a `Console.ReadLine()` to test this.

Comment: `while (true) { }` ???  At least a delay. Better is to fix it to a real solution

Comment: That was it thanks, noted for the future

Answer (score 0):

While true was blocking my thread